# building corda 4.8 on windows with intellij

Tags: corda

I get this error while building corda 4.8 on a windows 10 box using intellij:

Could not find javafx-controls-mac.jar (org.openjfx:javafx-controls:11.0.2).
Searched in the following locations:
file:/C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-controls/11.0.2/javafx-controls-11.0.2-mac.jar

I don't want to build the mac version, how can I disable or ignore the error?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something as far as context, but currently, you can only build corda with java 8. Java 11 is not supported yet. Take a look at this docs page for the specific tooling you need to configure CorDapps.

https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.7/getting-set-up.html

Long story short, until corda 5 is released you'll need java 8 to build cordapps which you can install here : https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html